# How to prevent line feeds (vbLf) and carriage returns (vbCr) in text boxes in a vb.net text file?

Tags: vb.net

How to prevent line feeds (vbLf) and carriage returns (vbCr) in a text box that should only be one line, in a text file? It can happen that these carriage return characters and these new line characters are present (for example during a copy and paste) in the body of the text and thus make the reading of the file impossible. This has happened to me before, and I think I need to set up a check for the presence of these characters and thus warn the user to check his line before any recording. Thank you in advance. Claude.

Comment: Are you saying that you are reading the file and displaying the contents in a `TextBox`, but you only want to do so if there are no line breaks in the file? Or are you saying that you are saving from a `TextBox` to a file and you want to make sure there are no line breaks in the data before saving?

Comment: Yes, I am saving to file line by line from a text box and want to make sure there are no line breaks in the data before saving.

Comment: Well that doesn't make any sense. How do you save "line by line" data that "has no lines"

Comment: The data is recorded line by line thanks to the contents of the textbox. I may have explained myself very poorly!

Comment: @CaiusJard, presumably the current `TextBox` content is considered one line and that content is appended to the file multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the CR and LF with nothing?

```
textBoxWithCrLf.Text.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
```

Note, this doesn't modify the contents of the textbox, it generates a new string with no CRLF, so you'd use it like:

```
somefilewriter.SomeWriteStringMethod( textBoxWithCrLf.Text.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "") )
```